# Merging jMeter result files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to use the jMeter merger to merge the result files (http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/), but it seems the plug-in is restricted to 4 files to be merged.
Any way I can merge more files (>100)?

The structure of the files seems simple enough (https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JtlFiles) so I am about to break bash and write my own, but wanted to know if something hadn't already been written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a jMeter output file based on your project:

```
jmeter -n -t ./project.jmx -l testresult.jtl
```

This will load the file `project.jmx`, run the test and save the result to `testresult.jtl`.

Once you have many of these result files, you can merge them using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Combines all results from files called testresult*.jtl into one file called merged.jtl"
echo "If merged.jtl exists, it will be overridden"

cat testresult*.jtl > merged.jtl

# Remove boundaries between tests
sed 's_<\/testResults>__g' merged.jtl > /tmp/sedmerged1
sed 's_<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>__g' /tmp/sedmerged1 > /tmp/sedmerged2
sed 's_<testResults version=\"1.2\">__g' /tmp/sedmerged2 > /tmp/sedmerged3

# Add wrappers
echo "</testResults>" >> /tmp/sedmerged3
sed '1i <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testResults version="1.2">' /tmp/sedmerged3 > merged.jtl
```

The script will create a file called `merged.jtl`.

Done.